# Ionic 5 print page overflow not working scrollable content

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, printing

I'm trying to print an Ionic 5 page. I'm using angular and the content is rendered in angular.
I've already set the overflow-y to visible, tried everything, but when I hit ctrl+P it only prints 1 page with the content cut.
[image: Content cut]

I've already added to the css the overflor-y but it seems that ionic renders the content inside a scrollable viewport.

app.component.scss:

```css
ion-app,
body,
ion-router-outlet,
app-test-print,
p{
    overflow: visible;
    contain: none;
    display: block;
}

.ion-page{
    contain: none!important;
}
```

test.print page:

```css
.print{
    overflow-y: visible;
    contain: none;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>test-print</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<p class="print">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lacus nulla,
  consectetur ullamcorper gravida sed, suscipit eu massa. Vestibulum ut felis
  sit amet nunc egestas fermentum vitae non diam. Phasellus tellus velit,
  tristique tempus justo non, imperdiet varius leo. Donec quis cursus nunc.
  Sed purus risus, blandit in dui et, facilisis blandit diam. Sed leo arcu,
  vestibulum eget justo et, pretium dignissim mauris. Vestibulum vehicula
  consectetur ante. ... 
  [LONG TEXT HERE]
</p>
```

I tried everything, but the content always get cut.
Could please someone help me.
Thank you !

Comment: I'm trying to figure out this same thing, any luck yet?